# create an array from objects in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array,

```
const boxes=[
    {
        "trolleyNo": "345A",
        "trolleyItems": [
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                "value": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                "label": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "value": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "label": "Bread Basket & Tongs"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc",
                "value": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc",
                "label": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc"
            }
        ],
        "cartType": "fullCart",
        "index": "FC-093"
    },
    {
        "trolleyNo": "560S",
        "trolleyItems": [
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "value": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "label": "Bread Basket & Tongs"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Crockery - Full Plates",
                "value": "Crockery - Full Plates",
                "label": "Crockery - Full Plates"
            }
        ],
        "cartType": "halfCart",
        "index": "FC-093"
    }
]
```

i have a source array

```
   const items= [
               {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a25",
            "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
                {
                    "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a24",
                    "name": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                    "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
                },
                
                {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a2b",
            "name": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a2d",
            "name": "Crew Meals",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a31",
            "name": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a32",
            "name": "Crockery - Full Plates",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
    
                ]
```

all the objects are not included because of the lengthy size of the array.

my intention is to create a new array which goes like

```
const final= [
        {
            "cartId": "full",
            "itemsCategory": [
                {
                    "categoryId": "645bbe9141332374a05919d2"
                },
                {
                    "categoryId": "645bbf960e37e37b5c18e37e"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cartId": "half",
            "itemsCategory": [
                {
                    "categoryId": "645bc57dd374a392f8226708"
                },
                {
                    "categoryId": "645bc588d374a392f8226709"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

here cartId will be the cartType in the boxes array.and itemsCategory array should be obtained by matching the name in the trolleyItems array of boxes array with the name of objects in items array and getting the _id of the object corresponding to the matching name in the items array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array.map` to loop thru the `boxes` and then form the object you want to return. Do the same for `trolleyItems` inside. Then use `array.find` to match the `customerId` with the `key` to get the `categoryId`

```
const final = boxes.map(box => {
  return {
    cartId: box.cartType,
    itemsCategory: box.trolleyItems.map(titem => {
      return {
        categoryId: items.find(item => item.customerId === titem.key)?._id
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Run the code below to see the output. Since you have repetitive keys in your trolleyItems, all categoryId on the output was also the same.

```js
const boxes= [
    {
        "trolleyNo": "345A",
        "trolleyItems": [
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                "value": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
                "label": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "value": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "label": "Bread Basket & Tongs"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc",
                "value": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc",
                "label": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc"
            }
        ],
        "cartType": "fullCart",
        "index": "FC-093"
    },
    {
        "trolleyNo": "560S",
        "trolleyItems": [
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "value": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
                "label": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "value": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
                "label": "Bread Basket & Tongs"
            },
            {
                "key": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc",
                "name": "Crockery - Full Plates",
                "value": "Crockery - Full Plates",
                "label": "Crockery - Full Plates"
            }
        ],
        "cartType": "halfCart",
        "index": "FC-093"
    }
];

const items= [
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a25",
            "name": "Bar Cart - Beer & Wine",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a24",
            "name": "Bar Cart - Liquor, Liqueur",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a2b",
            "name": "Bread Basket & Tongs",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a2d",
            "name": "Crew Meals",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a31",
            "name": "Crew Store - Cookies, juices, etc",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "646d96f669cad73dc5d14a32",
            "name": "Crockery - Full Plates",
            "customerId": "02f2c8e0-cd40-11ed-8563-092a964acecc"
        },
    
];

const final = boxes.map(box => {
  return {
    cartId: box.cartType,
    itemsCategory: box.trolleyItems.map(titem => {
      return {
        categoryId: items.find(item => item.customerId === titem.key)?._id
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log({final});
```